# how to check how many memory tacking code in android

Tags: java, android, profiling

My app is many  method code I want to know which code is tacking time or I heard about profiling can anybody explain it or any good free tool for testing android app memory .

Answer (score 0):

You can look at Android Studio > Android Monitor Tab.

Comment: what do you want to check for your App?

Comment: when i m swiching activity i want to check my asycktask how many mamory is consuming i m running 12 asyncktask

Comment: my app is taking time when i m swiching activity 1 to other